# Is there a QGIS tool or plugin that can identify multiple layers at once?

Tags: qgis, identify

For anyone familiar with [magic.gov.uk](http://www.magic.gov.uk/MagicMap.aspx) (a UK government web-based GIS) I can shortcut this question by saying that I'm looking for the equivalent of the identify tool. For others, this is a tool which produces a report identifying the value of all the properties of any polygon from all selected layers on a click of the mouse.

So, say I had three layers, one with counties (name, population, area), one with nature reserves (name, area, type of reserve) and one with habitat (type, rarity, conservation status). I would like to be able to click on a point on the map (or draw a polygon), and produce a report which would list all the features from all the layers under that point, together with their attributes.

I'm using QGIS 2.18, but soon 3.

Answer (score 5):

If you select the Mode "Top down" in the "Identify Results" panel, you get info about the items from all the layers in your project when you use the Identify tool. This works in QGIS 2.18 and 3.x.

[image: Top Down mode in Identify results]